# Autohiding of GWT popup panel

Tags: java, gwt

How to hide GWT DecoratedPopupPanel after some time? I can make it with Timer class, but may be exist some more elegant way?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe GWT `Scheduler` is more elegant way for your task than timer.

See [`scheduleFixedDelay`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/core/client/Scheduler.html#scheduleFixedDelay%28com.google.gwt.core.client.Scheduler.RepeatingCommand,%20int%29)

Comment: thank for answer. As I have understood this is REPEATING command?

Comment: That's low-level API, please don't use if you understand absolutely

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely not. You must create a Timer object to handle it

Answer (score 0):

if you want to hide it when user clicks outside it you can specify autohide property

```
DecoratedPopupPanel

public DecoratedPopupPanel(boolean autoHide,
                           boolean modal)

    Creates an empty decorated popup panel, specifying its "auto-hide" and "modal" properties.

    Parameters:
        autoHide - true if the popup should be automatically hidden when the user clicks outside of it
        modal - true if keyboard or mouse events that do not target the PopupPanel or its children should be ignored
```

refer [javaDoc](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DecoratedPopupPanel.html)

other option is Timer class as you have discovered.